# MongoDB Query for Values over Multiple Time Intervals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Fairly new to MongoDB, I have a collection that holds multiple documents. I need a query that gives the a document value over multiple time intervals. For instance, I need a value from 1 minute ago, 5 minutes ago, 10 minutes ago and so on.

Currently I do this to get what I need.

I create an object of the different timeIntervals I need

```
var timeIntervals = {
    "1Min" : 60000,
    "5Min" : 300000,
    "10Min" : 600000,
    "30Min" : 1800000,
}
```

and then loop through them and perform this query on each interval to get the value I need.

```
db.collection.findOne({TimeStamp:{$gt: new Date(currentTime - timeInterval)})
```

While this does what I need, it is terribly inefficient especially if I need to add larger or more precise intervals. Is there a better more efficient way of performing this operation?

Thanks!

EDIT

Here is a more through example of what I'm trying to do.

I have a backend that receives stock ticker prices in real time for particular symbols so it receives hundreds a second. Each time a new price comes in it gets timestamped and stored in a MongoDB. Each time a new price comes in I need to get the price change for the last 1 Minute, 5 Minutes, 10 Minutes etc. So I can see how the price is varying over those intervals. And then store that data in a different collection.

Comment: That's still quite abstract. What do you "really" want to do? Because all this is doing is returning the first document that matches at each boundary. You probably should explain what you really need to do and what sort of "new complexity" it actually needs to handle. Also why mongojs? It's one of those libraries that was introduced at a time when there was some features missing from the core driver. That time is passed, so it does raise the question. And ideally you really want something with full Promise support.

Comment: @NeilLunn The database holds price data over time, and I am trying to calculate the price change over the different time intervals I posted above. So when a new price metric comes in, I insert it into the database and then perform the operation i showed above to get the price change as a percentage over the different time intervals. Also I just happened upon mongojs not married to it by any means.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that further with a brief example of the flow of data you receive, what needs to happen and when. If this is really about "reporting" then you probably want to "accumulate" things as you go, rather than query after the fact. A search for ["mongodb time series"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+time+series) should give you some pointers on approaches to "collecting" data as it is received over required intervals and keeping it together for such purposes.

Comment: Why don't you just query for your biggest timestamp (30min in your case) and group results in intervals manually, using a single loop? Is it because you need the latest inserted document for the given interval? (this guess is based on the use of `findOne()`)?

Comment: @wscourge I did consider getting all the data in one call with the biggest timestamp but I was thinking it may cause issues later one since there will be many entries per second in the database and my timestamp may be 7+ days eventually. So you are right I only need the latest inserted document for the given interval hence the findOne(). I updated my question with a little more detail on what I'm trying to do exactly.